# Can the spreadsheet table decision be out the jar?

Tags: java, drools, spreadsheet

I try to work with table decision in excel format (*.xlsx), a spreadsheet. I don't want to put my spreadsheet in the folder resource of my application. So I created a folder : folder/Discount.xls.

But when I run my program a File not found exception it throws. It seems the spreadsheet file can't be load if it is not in the resource folder, so in the jar.

I would to know if I can make a program when the spreadsheed, for my rules can be load dynamically ? I would choose one or another spreadsheet for making hot change of my rules. But I don't know if it possible.

I have some code :

```
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    File file = new File("folder/Discount.xls");
    Resource resource = ResourceFactory.newFileResource(file);
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem().write(resource);
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
    ReleaseId krDefaultReleaseId = kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(krDefaultReleaseId);
    KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
```

The previous code throw a runtime exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: org.default:artifact:1.0.0
```

Comment: Show us some code please, but basically you will need to use an absolute path and some means of getting an input for that absolute path.

Comment: I have added a snippet but it doesn't work, I search a proof of concept but for now can't find it

Comment: The exception you pasted does not say the program cannot find the file, it says you are missing a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution of my problem. The spreadsheet can be in another folder than the java resource folder. My class test is the following :

```
public class Main {

    private static InternalKnowledgeBase createKnowledgeBaseFromSpreadsheet() throws Exception {

        DecisionTableConfiguration decisionTableConfiguration = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration();
        decisionTableConfiguration.setInputType(DecisionTableInputType.XLS);
        KnowledgeBuilder knowledgeBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
        File file = new File("folder/Discount.xls");
        Resource resourceFile = ResourceFactory.newFileResource(file);
        knowledgeBuilder.add(resourceFile, ResourceType.DTABLE, decisionTableConfiguration);

        if (knowledgeBuilder.hasErrors()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(knowledgeBuilder.getErrors().toString());
        }

        InternalKnowledgeBase internalKnowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
        Collection<KiePackage> kiePackages = knowledgeBuilder.getKnowledgePackages();
        internalKnowledgeBase.addPackages(kiePackages);
        return internalKnowledgeBase;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        (new Main()).run();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("--- Start Code ---");
        StatelessKieSession session = null;

        try {
            InternalKnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = createKnowledgeBaseFromSpreadsheet();
            session = knowledgeBase.newStatelessKieSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Customer customer = new Customer(CustomerType.INDIVIDUAL, 1);
        System.out.println(customer.toString());
        session.execute(customer);
        System.out.println(customer.toString());
        System.out.println("--- End Code ---");
    }
}
```

My customer class (must add the getter, setter and overhide the toString method) :

```
public class Customer {

    public enum CustomerType {
        INDIVIDUAL, BUSINESS;
    }
    private CustomerType type;
    private int years;
    private int discount;

    public Customer(CustomerType individual, int years) {
        this.type = individual;
        this.years = years;
    }
}
```

My *.pom file contains :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
        <version>7.28.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
        <version>7.28.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```